# Speed module mass

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A mass body $m$ slides without friction on the flat (and inclined from an angle α to horizontal) surface of a mass block $M$ under spring action, shown in the figure.  This spring, of elastic constant k and natural length $C$, has its ends respectively attached to the mass body m and the block.  In turn, the block can slide without friction on the flat and horizontal surface on which it rests.  The body is pulled to a position where the spring is stretched elastically to a length $L (L>C)$ such that upon release the body passes the position where the tensile force is zero.  In this position, the block velocity modulus is:

[image]

a)$\sqrt{\frac{2m[\frac{1}{2}k(L-C)^2-mg(L-C)sin(\alpha)}{M^2[1+sin^2(\alpha)]}}$

b)$\sqrt{\frac{2m[\frac{1}{2}k(L-C)^2-mg(L-C)sin(\alpha)}{M^2[1+tan^2(\alpha)]}}$

c) $\sqrt{\frac{2m[\frac{1}{2}k(L-C)^2-mg(L-C)sin(\alpha)}{(m+M)[(m+M)tan^2(\alpha)+M]}}$

d)$\sqrt{\frac{2m[\frac{k}{2}k(L-C)^2]}{M^2[1+tan^2(\alpha)]}}$

e) 0

I tried to do $\alpha = 0$, replace in alternatives, and see that the alternatives are just one change. Ae solve in the plan where I considered $\alpha = 0$

Can someone help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should use energy conservation.  How much energy is added to the system when the string is stretched?  Remember the loss because the mass is lower.  That is the kinetic energy when the string is at natural length.

Comment: @RossMillikan Have another method? This will make a huge calculation

Comment: It can't be a small calculation looking at the answers you have to choose from.  You also have to use momentum conservation because the block slides.

Comment: If you write conservation of momentum and energy for $\alpha=0$ you can get the velocity. If you plug in $\alpha=0$ into your answers, you will match only one. And it's only 5 simple lines

Comment: I don't see your efforts to solve the issue.